# How to get the I.P Address and Port Number of Zebra Printer?

Tags: android, printing, ip, zebra-printers, zpl

am trying to connect to Zebra Printer, Model GK420t, via Android Application in order sendFileContents to the Zebra printer, using the ZSDK, where i need to use the TCPConnection() constructor, in which requires the I.P Address and Port number of the printer as parameters, but i can't figure out how to get the I.P Address and Port Number of the Zebra printer,

Note, am assigning the Port number as the default using "TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT"

Please Advise,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you have never configured the printer, your best bet is to run the Zebra Setup Utilities available at:  https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printer-software/printer-setup-utilities.html#featureforoperatings

Answer (score 3):

Make sure, the printer is on and the coverage is closed.

Press and hold the **feed button** until the **status LED flashes one time**. Then release the feed button and a series of status information labels gets printed, including the network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I did that on the GK420t that I currently connect to my laptp via the USB port. My printout does not show anything looking like an IP address. Closest is FIRMWARE showing as V61.17.172

Comment: If you are replying to @Delphi Coder 's answer then please post it as a comment to his answer rather than as a complete answer of your own (since it is a comment on his answer, not an actual answer.)

Answer (score 0):

it prints "Printer Configuration" first (20< tabs or so), when its done, press the feed button once more to get the network settings (10 tabs long)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).